# why does it shows segmentation fault in the while statement?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack

I want to know the cause of the error. If I invert the relational operator in the while statement there is no error and it
generates output but in the following code, it doesn't give any output and gives a segmentation error while debugging.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  stack<int> h;
  h.push(1);
  h.push(2);
  h.push(3);
  h.push(4);
  h.push(5);
  h.push(6);
  h.push(7);
  h.push(8);
  h.push(9);
  h.push(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !h.empty(); i++) {
    while (h.top() < 6) {  // This is the point where it shows a segmentation
                           // fault in the debugger
      h.pop();
    }
    cout << h.top() << " ";
    h.pop();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to be sure `h` is not empty before each `top()` and `pop()` call. You can put some assertions there to see that your program logic is wrong. Shouldn't the while condition be `h.top()>6`?

Comment: you call `top` on an empty stack which causes undefined behaviour

Comment: what happens when you already popped all elements till 6 and then inside the loop continue to pop elements while `top < 6` ? How is this while loop supposed to stop?

Answer (score 3):

Before you enter the loop, the stack is this:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
^- top
```

After 5 iterations of the for loop the stack is this (each iteration pops one element, and because they are all not <6 the while loop does nothing):

```
5 4 3 2 1
^- top
```

Now when this stack is fed to

```
while(h.top() < 6){
    h.pop();
}
```

you will never reach a state where `h.top < 6` is `false`, hence the loop never stops to pop elements from the stack. Eventually you call `h.top()` on an empty stack and invoke undefined behavior. A segfault is one possible outcome.

You do not see the output of the previous iterations, because there is no way the code does not invoke undefined behavior. Hence, the whole program has undefined behavior. It is not the case that it works well until it crashes. However, in this case flushing the stream (eg via `std::endl`) will likely produce some output before the crash. It does here https://godbolt.org/z/z4fcvTse4.

---

When the condition in the while loop is `h.top() > 6` this doesn't happen, because the final elements in the stack are all `<6` and make the loop stop before the stack is empty. However, the right way would be to check if the stack is empty before calling `top` just as you do in the for loop:

```
    while(!h.empty() && h.top() < 6){
        h.pop();
    }
    if (!h.empty()) {
        cout<<h.top()<<" ";
        h.pop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the stack is empty or not. Otherwise in the `while` you are trying to get reference to `null`.

Try to replace your `for` cycle with this:

```
for(int i=0;i<10 && !h.empty();i++) {
    while(!h.empty() && h.top() < 6) {
        h.pop();
    }
    if (h.empty())
        break;
    cout<<h.top()<<" ";
    h.pop();
}
```